# mac automator multiple instances of app with selected file

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I am writing an automator script that should open a new instance of the app fslview everytime I double click on a selected nii.gz file. All attempts to "run shell script" using the & operator, to make fslview run in the background, failed. I managed to use "run applescript" with

```
do shell script "open -n /usr/local/fsl/bin/fslview"
```

to open multiple instances of fslview. How do I pass the path and name of the selected file from "get selected finder items" to fslview? The terminal command I use for my desired behavior looks like this:

fslview some_image.nii.gz &

Thanks in advance,
Martin

BTW: when I run the following script I get an infinte loop of opening fslview apps

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set f to (input as text)
    set f to POSIX path of f
    do shell script "open -n /usr/local/fsl/bin/fslview.app " & f
end run
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set f to POSIX path of (input as text)
    do shell script "source ~/.bash_profile"
    do shell script "open -n -a fslview.app --args " & f
end run
```